# Attempt to de-reference a null object An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: apex

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="SchemaObjects">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Object List" />
                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedobj}">  
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!objects}" />
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!details}" reRender="od" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!objDescription}" id="od" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller

```
public with sharing class SchemaObjects {

    public List<SelectOption> objects {set; get;}
    public List<String> objlst {set; get;}
    public Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mobjects {set; get;}
    public String selectedobj {set; get;}
    public String objDescription {set; get;}
    public SchemaObjects() {
        mobjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        objlst.addAll(mobjects.keySet());
        objlst.sort();
        for (String s : objlst) {
            if (s !=null) {
                SelectOption op = new SelectOption(s,s);
                objects.add(op);
            }

        }
    }
    public void details(){
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult myobj= mobjects.get(selectedobj).getDescribe();
        objDescription=''+myobj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your question to include the complete, verbatim error message and stack trace in the body of your question, and identify the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: `NullPointerException` is usually pretty easy to trace just by looking at your code. Since you do not initialize it, `selectedobj` is probably your culprit.

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 separate collections in your controller which you later dereference. The first one (`mobjects`) you assign a value beforehand, so that does not throw any `NullPointerException`. However, neither of the other two ever gets assigned. When you declare a variable but do not assign a value, it is null. Simply construct your other two collections at the beginning of your constructor.

```
public SchemaObjects() {
    mobjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    objList = new List<String>(mobjects.keySet());
    objects = new List<SelectOption>();
    // rest of logic
}
```